# Why do the following Network Transformations give different answers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics

I did a Star to Delta Network Transformation and a Delta to Star Network Transformation on different parts of the original circuit as shown in the image below.

It gave me two new circuits. On solving those circuits, I get different answers for the equivalent resistance. Why is this so?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an error in the star-delta transformed circuit (1). You overlooked that the delta branch of 4 Ohm at terminal (a) is short circuited.

Answer (score 0):

**Because you've made a mistake in your application of the formalism.**

Both of the transformations you have performed are guaranteed, when done correctly, to produce completely equivalent circuits. The only thing that can break here is the 'done correctly' part ─ so double- and triple-check all your algebra.

Ultimately, if you want a higher standard which you can use to hold both of those answers to, you need to do a full Kirchhoff's-Laws analysis of the circuit, which will (when done correctly) give an unambiguous answer for the total resistance of the circuit.

As to *where* you've made a mistake, that's not within our purview; please read [these guidelines](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [these ones](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for more information.

Comment: This is just a generic answer according to the principle: *If you hadn't made a mistake, you would have got the correct result.* To help the OP, you should point out the actual mistake.